# Insert the record from csv file into database table will not fetch record from first column in a series

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I will send you the code that I have used to insert data from csv file into database table but it will not insert data from the beginning and continuous to the last record instead it fetch record randomly please suggest me changes in my current code so that it will fetch the record from the beginning continuous to the last fetch each and every record from the csv file

```
 <?php
 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 set_time_limit(0);
 if (!$connect) 
 {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
 }
 $cid=mysql_select_db("bond1",$connect);
 define("CSV_PATH","D:/wamp/www/csvfile/");                                                       

 $csv_file=CSV_PATH."file.csv";
 $csvfile=fopen($csv_file, 'r');
 $theData=fgets($csvfile);
 $i=0;

 while(!feof($csvfile))
 {
 $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile,1024);
 $csv_array=explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
 $insert_csv=array();
 $insert_csv['name']=$csv_array[0];
 $insert_csv['address']='http://'.$csv_array[1];
 $insert_csv['duns_number']=$csv_array[2];
 $insert_csv['idnum']=$csv_array[3];

 $query="insert into  companyinfo(name,address,duns_number,id_number)values('".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['address']."','".$insert_csv['duns_number']."','".$insert_csv['idnum']."')";
  $n=mysql_query($query,$connect);
  ++$i;
  }
  fclose($csvfile);
  echo "File data successfully imported to database!!";
  mysql_close($connect);
  ?>
```

Comment: set_time_limit(0);
$i=0;
while(!feof($csvfile))
{
$csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile,1024);
$csv_array=explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
$insert_csv=array();
$insert_csv['name']=$csv_array[0];
$insert_csv['address']='http://'.$csv_array[1];
$insert_csv['duns_number']=$csv_array[2];
$insert_csv['idnum']=$csv_array[3];
"insert into companyinfo(name,address,duns_number,id_number)values('".$insert_csv['name']."','".$insert_csv['address']."','".$insert_csv['duns_number']."','".$insert_csv['idnum']."')"; 
++$i;
}
?>

Comment: Please add this code to you post not in comments. it is heard to read

Comment: I have send you the code in the post please see to it.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Use that function to automatically parse csv to an array .

Comment: if I want to skip the record that have already entered in the database that changes has to be done in the current code

Answer (score 0):

This will help you further

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
$i = 0;

//create database connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

while (!feof($csvfile)) 
{
    $csv_data = fgets($csvfile, 1024);

//if it is first row skip here  || if any value is empty then skip the row
 if($i==0 || 
    (empty($csv_array[0]) || 
     empty($csv_array[1]) ||
     empty($csv_array[2]) ||
     empty($csv_array[3])))
    {
        ++$i;

        //continue the loop
        continue;
    }

    $csv_array = explode(",", $csv_data);
    $insert_csv = array();
    $insert_csv['name'] = $csv_array[0];
    $insert_csv['address'] = 'http://' . $csv_array[1];
    $insert_csv['duns_number'] = $csv_array[2];
    $insert_csv['idnum'] = $csv_array[3];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO companyinfo(name,address,duns_number,id_number)
            VALUES('" . $insert_csv['name'] . "',‌
            ​'" . $insert_csv['address'] . "',
            '" . $insert_csv['duns_number'] . "',
            '" . $insert_csv['idn‌​um'] . "')";

    //insert the query
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) 
    {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```

Comment: how to filter the data from the csv file so that if the coloumn is blank in the csv file that record will not insert into database

Comment: check the updated answer if any value is empty in the csv file then skip that row

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking in while loop feof of file pointer

like     `while(!feof($csvfile))`

move your  `fgets($csvfile,1024);` inside while loop

```
 while (($csv_data = fgets($csvfile, 4096)) !== false) {
```

and change you code below. hopefully it will fix your issue.